# authentication user with LDAP using spring security

Tags: spring-security, ldap

I am trying to provide authentication to user using LDAP in an spring security application , I am quiet new to spring security and LDAP , I have taken help from the following tutorial
http://krams915.blogspot.in/2011/01/spring-security-mvc-using-ldap.html
This is an maven project but I am not using maven eventhough I added all the jars required I am getting the following exception ..please suggest ..

```
ERROR [Thread-3] (ContextLoader.java:220) - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean] while setting bean property 'parent'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider#0' while setting bean property 'providers' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.securityContextSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.securityContextSource': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:281)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:125)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5226)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$1.call(StandardContext.java:5221)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider#0' while setting bean property 'providers' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.securityContextSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.securityContextSource': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:109)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:274)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider#0' while setting bean property 'providers' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider#0': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator] while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#1': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.securityContextSource' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.securityContextSource': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:153)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd 
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Activates various annotations to be detected in bean classes -->
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Scans the classpath for annotated components that will be auto-registered as Spring beans.
     For example @Controller and @Service. Make sure to set the correct base-package-->
    <context:component-scan base-package="controllers" />

    <!-- Configures the annotation-driven Spring MVC Controller programming model.
    Note that, with Spring 3.0, this tag works in Servlet MVC only!  -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven /> 

</beans>
```

**spring-security.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- This is where we configure Spring-Security -->
    <security:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"
        access-denied-page="/krams/auth/denied">

        <security:intercept-url pattern="/krams/auth/login"
            access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/krams/main/admin"
            access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/krams/main/common"
            access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

        <security:form-login login-page="/krams/auth/login"
            authentication-failure-url="/krams/auth/login?error=true"
            default-target-url="/krams/main/common" />

        <security:logout invalidate-session="true"
            logout-success-url="/krams/auth/login" logout-url="/krams/auth/logout" />

      </security:http>

    <!-- For authentication: user-search-filter: the attribute name that contains 
        the user name user-search-base: the base path where to find user information 
        For authorization: group-search-filter: the attribute name that contains 
        the full dn of a user group-search-base: the base path where to find role 
        information group-role-attribute: the attribute name that contains the role 
        type role-prefix: the prefix to be added when retrieving role values For 
        server access: manager-dn: the full dn of the person that has access to an 
        LDAP server manager-password: the password of the person that has access 
        to an LDAP server -->
    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:ldap-authentication-provider
            user-search-filter="(uid={0})" user-search-base="ou=users"
            group-search-filter="(uniqueMember={0})" group-search-base="ou=groups"
            group-role-attribute="cn" role-prefix="ROLE_">
        </security:ldap-authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <security:ldap-server url="ldap://localhost:11389/o=vtu"
        manager-dn="uid=admin,ou=system" manager-password="secret" />
</beans>
```

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Declare a view resolver -->
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" 
            p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/" p:suffix=".jsp" />

   </beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <filter>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        /WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/krams/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>

        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

Comment: would be helpful if you post your spring configuration file(s)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the following jar as a maven dependency:

http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.3

When I encounter ClassNotjava.lang.NoClassDefFoundError I search for that class in http://mvnrepository.com to find what jar I need as a dependency.

To add a new maven dependency look for the pom.xml file in your project and add the dependency as shown in the maven tab of the first 
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.3

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

The very last exception has caused the other exceptions. It says:

```
Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils
```

Which means you are missing the class StringUtils, which can be found in the jar file here:
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.0